# add data to mongodb using jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, mongodb

my HTML code

```
<section>
    <div class="container " style="height: 55vh;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1 icon-content-wraper">
                <h2> add products</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1">
                <form id="form" action="newadd.php" method="post">

                    <div class="col-1 ">
                        add product:
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <input type="text" id="reference" name="reference" placeholder=" " required>
                            <label for="reference">Product reference number</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <input type="text" id="stock_amount" name="stock_amount" placeholder=" " required>
                            <label for="stock_amount">Product stock amount</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <input type="text" id="product_name" name="product_name" placeholder=" " required>
                            <label for="product_name">Product name</label>
                        </div>
                        
                        Product cattegory: <div class="input-container">
                            <select class="sort" name="category" id="category">
                                <option value="1">Salty
                                <option value="2" selected="">Sweet
                                <option value="3" selected="">Chocolate
                                <option value="4" selected="">Sour
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-container">
                            <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea>
                            <span for="description">description</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <input type="text" id="price" name="price" placeholder=" " required>
                            <label for="price">Product price</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <input type="text" id="tax" name="tax" placeholder=" " required>
                            <label for="tax">Product tax</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <input type="text" id="discount" name="discount" placeholder=" " required>
                            <label for="discount">Product discount</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 mt-60">
                        <input id="Add" class="btn-standard" type="submit" name="Add" value="Add" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</section>


<div class="article-progress-bar"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" >
        
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form").submit(function(e){
          
             e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
              
                type: "POST",
                url: "newadd.php",
                dataType:"json",

                data:{
                    Reference:$("#reference").val(),
                    Stock: $("#stock_amount").val(),
                    ProductName: $("#product_name").val(),
                    Category: $("#category: selected").text(),
                    Description: $("#description").val(),
                    Price: $("#price").val(),
                    Tax: $("#tax").val(),
                    Discount: $("#discount").val()
                    },
                    
                success: function(response){
                    alert(response);
                    if (response == 1){
                        
                        window.location="cms-view-products.php";
                        
                    }
                    else if (response == 0){
                        alert("error to add data");
                    }
                }   
            })
                
        });
    });
 </script>
```

my PHP code

```
<?php

....

//Extract the data that was sent to the server
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){

$reference = $_POST['reference'];
$stock = $_POST['Stock'];
$name = $_POST['ProductName'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$description = $_POST['Description'];
$price = $_POST['Price'];
$tax = $_POST['Tax'];
$discount = $_POST['Discount'];


//Convert to PHP array
$dataArray = [
    $Tag => [
    "Reference" => $reference,
    "StockAmount" => $stock
],
    "Name" => $name, 
    "Description" => $description, 
    "Category" => $category,
    "Tax" => $tax, 
    "Rating" => " ",
    "Discount" => $discount, 
    "Price" => $price
];

//Add the new product to the database
$insertResult = $collection->insertOne($dataArray);

//Echo result back to user
if($insertResult->getInsertedCount()){
    echo 1;
    
}
else {
    echo 0;
}


}
else {
    echo 'connection Error';
}
```

The error is that it adds null fields to the database plus:
Warning: Undefined array key "Stock" in C:\xampp\htdocs\newadd.php on line 19

Warning: Undefined array key "ProductName" in C:\xampp\htdocs\newadd.php on line 20

Warning: Undefined array key "Description" in C:\xampp\htdocs\newadd.php on line 22

Warning: Undefined array key "Price" in C:\xampp\htdocs\newadd.php on line 23
etc.

Comment: you mean in the Jquery part,?
but I thought this is the ID part ("#reference") and it match the ID in the HTML tag

Comment: Ah.. missed that you were using Ajax.

Comment: Is the form actually sent using that Ajax code? If it did, you should get other "Undefined keys", like `reference` and `category` and the errors only make sense if it wasn't sent through Ajax. Where do you see those errors? Check in the consoles of you have any errors that causes that JS not to execute. Are you including jquery in the header or at the end of the page?

Comment: jquery  it at the end of the page. and the form is submitted using the jquery .$ajax.

Comment: The errors indicates that the form is submitted "normally". You never answered where you see those errors? You need to put that JS code (your ajax code) after you've included jQuery. Did you do as I sugested and checked the browsers development console?

Comment: after the form has been submitted the browser open a new white page and show the errors. and yes there is no errors in the console

Comment: Then it's not being submitted using Ajax. The whole point of Ajax is to make the request in the background so you _don't_ redirect to another page.